# Trouble with makefile when installing PyLucene

Tags: makefile, lucene, pylucene

I am trying to build PyLucene on my Windows 10 machine. Here are the details I am currently providing on the Makefile:

```
PREFIX_PYTHON=C:\\Users\\Charlie\\Anaconda3
ANT=C:\\Program Files\\apache-ant-1.10.5\\bin\\ant
JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.2
PYTHON=$(PREFIX_PYTHON)\python.exe
JCC = $(PYTHON) -m jcc
NUM_FILES = 8
```

When I run  'make' from the command line, I encounter the following error:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, which icupkg, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.
cd lucene-java-7.6.0/lucene; (C:\\Program Files\\apache-ant-1.10.5\\bin\\ant ivy-availability-check || C:\\Program Files\\apache-ant-1.10.5\\bin\\ant ivy-bootstrap)
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
'C:\\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make: *** [ivy] Error 1
```

Can someone provide any insight as to what is going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
JAVA_HOME="C:\\"Program Files"\\Java\\jdk-11.0.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

This error tells that the syntax is incorrect.

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
'C:\\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

In this case you have a **space** in your path for ANT and JAVA_HOME, e.g- C:\Program Files (notice the space between *Program* and *Files*).

When you have spaces between your path, always write them in double quotes, like-

```
ANT       = "C:\\Program Files\\apache-ant-1.10.5\\bin\\ant"
JAVA_HOME = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.2"
```